# Worth moving to Hibernate ORM from JDBC Prepared statements after the project is 90% done?

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, orm

I have a Rest Api Project which is using a database of around 25 to 30 tables. This project was built using JDBC Prepared statements.
The project is huge. Since I got to know hibernate orm is better for maintenance I thought I should migrate to Hibernate ORM. I have a intermediate experience in Hibernate. After I started working I had to create POJO classes which are different from my previous pojo classes, because hibernate annotation uses bean classes with mapping for other tables as well. Its getting messed up everywhere changing everything.Is it worth migrating to Hinernate ORM after my project is 90% done?

- My Business objects are changing.
- Dao is different from previous ones.
- Controller Also needs modificatons.

Comment: it is not worth, think how to structure existing code to be more verbose and easier to navigate and find interesting things, then try to refactor it bit by bit.

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki can you please elaborate a little?

Comment: Changing DB access code in a huge 90% done project will be like opening pandora box with unknow and scary bugs waiting to see the daylight, those bugs (amount and unexpectancy of them) will eat your time and probably profit from the project.

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki I agree with you. There is lot of structure change. And I think to implement hibernate the project needs to planned well according to the database structure.

Comment: Hibernate is not better than plain JDBC. So if you don't have really important reason for such change, don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are 90% complete, it certainly isn't something I would rush to do immediately.  I would continue to maintain your current implementation strategy at least for now.

But this is precisely one of the pitfalls developers fall into when they elect to reuse the same model classes at various layers in their application.  When you want to introduce a new piece of technology or make a radical change at a lower level, all layers that sit atop of that are affected.  This leads to serious technical debt downstream that should be avoided.

Simple, prototype based applications can certainly get away with this type of code reuse, but more sophisticated, complex applications should not for the reasons I stated above.

What you could look to do is refactor the code so that you have cleaner and more clearer boundaries between the various layers of the application.  The ideal scenario is something like:

- Persistence models (these are your `@Entity` classes)
- Domain models (these are what your services take as input and return as output)
- View models (these are what your controllers take as input and return as output)

Each layer would then contain some amount of *mapping* code which knows how to take one model type to the next, something like this:

- Controller takes a view-model and maps it to a domain model
- Controller calls service with your domain model
- Service calls a repository with the domain model
- Repository takes a domain model and maps it to a persistence model
- Repository calls Hibernate with the persistence model

Many may view this as unnecessary abstraction and as I pointed out, in simple and basic use cases, that's true.  But the benefit here is that you avoid unnecessary cohesion between layers when you start to separate them like this.

At a minimum, it's worth a split between view and persistence models.  This allows you to model the structure of your datastore where it makes the most sense while allowing the option for a completely different exposed REST interface.  This way as requirements change on either end of the spectrum, they are free to do so with only having to address the mapping code that sits between them.

Comment: I Appreciate your answer . But can you give me a basic idea of how domain model (which i have currently) can be mapped to persistence model (`@Entity` classes which will be generated by hibernate tools) ?.. Thanks.

Comment: I disagree, you don't need to have such layers - it is misunderstaning, you can structure your code like you wish, for example there could be even feature centric structure, where all components for a feature share same package and sit together, rather than being splitted into layers which are not correlated to the features your app have. And the second statement of "mappings beetween layers" is even worse, it sounds like unfamous DTO pattern, it just brings additional complexity, where you can simply use existing classess, so the app don't need layers - it is not an onion.

Comment: There is always trade-offs @KrzysztofCichocki.  In the frameworks I work on, its common to abstract a particular layer's model away from other layers to avoid unintended exposure of internals which aren't meant to be made available.  The same argument can be made in this case too.  Sure you can reuse the same entity classes, but as I point out, its really critical to expose your view using different models so that at least the input/output of the application can evolve with time without the unnecessary coupling to your data-model.  There are cases where that isn't as important, but that's rare

Comment: @ArjunNayak I would first treat whatever model your REST api exposes as your view model since likely that is something which you cannot change, it is in fact what consumers of your REST api expect.  How you then wish to store the data in your data-store becomes the question.  Is how you are storing it logical, is it normalized, etc.  From there you build your data models for your `@Entity` classes.